# centering variable width span on top fixed size image with jquery

Tags: jquery

Here is the **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LK2jq/)**

```
//Fade in and out animation on hove buttons - icon set, features.
$(window).load(function() {
    $("ul#features_icons li img").hover(function() {
        $(this).next("span").animate({ opacity: "show" }, "fast");
    }, function() {
        $(this).next("span").animate({opacity: "hide"}, "fast");
    });
});
```

I'm trying to accomplish a hover on effect, where contents of the span will be display:none, but as soon as you hover on it will become display:block. With css I managed to put it on the top of the image by using negative margin, but my problem is to center this span in relation to the image.

Any ideas?

with css it is not possible. So must be with jquery something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### *[demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LK2jq/2/)*

We have to calculate the center of the image (width/2) and the center of the span (width/2).
After we have this `var`s we can play with the **span's** `marginLeft`.

```
var spanW = 0;
var imgW = $('li img').width()/2;
$(window).load(function() {
    $("ul#features_icons li img").hover(function() {
        spanW = $(this).next("span").width()/2;
        $(this).next("span").css({marginLeft: -spanW-imgW }).stop().animate({ opacity: "show" }, "fast");
    }, function() {
        $(this).next("span").stop().animate({opacity: "hide"}, "fast");
    });
});
```

I even added the `.stop()` before your animations to prevent animation bubblings
(fast mousemoves over your elements issue).